# Why most of the data on neutron cross-sections are tabulated at 0.0253 eV?

Tags: nuclear-physics

I have seen often this parameter more than 1 MeV. Its some sort of normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the thermal energy of a Neutron at room temperature - http://holbert.faculty.asu.edu/eee562/ThermalNeutronFlux.pdf

(why this should be used I have no idea)

Comment: Thermal cross-sections are interesting because neutrons bouncing around a  environment that your basic Mk I human can tolerate thermalize quickly and spend most of their brief existence as independent particles in the neighborhood of that energy. And the usual low precision value for BoTE calculations and such is 1/40 eV, which you can see is quite close.

Comment: @ dmckee I am not sure but is it an important parameter for nuclear reactors?

Comment: @Farcher Reactors are a hotter environment and therefore the thermal energy is a bit hgiher. Though the boiling water kind are only about a fourth hotter (gotta use absolute unit, of course).